# Initial state in F# List.scan

Tags: f#

I have a simple problem and as I'm an F# newbie I can't seem to figure out how to do this. I have a list of tuples:

```
let l = [ (a, 2); (b, 3); (c, 2); (d, 6) ]
```

that I want to transform into this:

```
let r = [ (a, 2); (b, 5); (c, 7); (d, 13) ]
```

This simply adds the values of the second element in each tuple: `2 + 3 + 2 + 6`. The objects `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` are complex objects that I simply want to keep.

I thought I should use `List.scan` for this. It takes a list, threads an accumulator through the computation and returns a list:

```
let r = l |> List.scan (fun (_, s) (o, i) -> (o, s + i)) (??, 0) |> List.tail
```

But I don't know what to fill in for the question marks. I'm not interested in the initial state except for the `0`. And I don't want to specify some 'empty' instance of the first tuple element.

Or is there a simpler way of doing this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use first element as an initial state:

```
let l = [ ("a", 2); ("b", 3); ("c", 2); ("d", 6) ]

let x::xs = l
let res = (x, xs) ||> List.scan (fun (_, x) (o, n) -> o, x + n) // [("a", 2); ("b", 5); ("c", 7); ("d", 13)]
```

Special case with empty list should be processed separately

Comment: That's the kind of simple solution I was looking for. Thanks. I haven't encountered the ||> operator before, but I suppose it simply pipes two operands into the expression?

Comment: Yes, it is double pipeline operator, defined like: let (||>) (a,b) f = f a b